# Make left-shift only capitalize certain keys, right-shift the rest

Tags: xmodmap, shift

I use Arch Linux and xmodmap for customizing keys. I'm in the process of learning Touch Typing. Now for my typing behavior, I exclusively use left-shift for capitalization. I would like to integrate using the right-shift into my typing flow, however I'm having a rough time getting used to it. Now my idea to enforce this behavior is to make it so that letters I type with my left hand can only be capitalized using the right shift.

So my question is: how do I disable the left-shift (capitalization) for a certain set of keys, i.e. the ones I trigger using my left hand.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a working solution. In `.Xmodmap` file (you can look up the syntax [here](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xmodmap_tutorial.html)), you remap right-shift to be the `mode_switch` key and then remap each key you want to only capitalize when the `mode_switch` key is pressed. For instance, the letter q, which is by default mapped as:

```
keycode 24 = q Q q Q at Greek_OMEGA
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
keycode 24 = q VoidSymbol Q Q at Greek_OMEGA
```

Complete mappings, i.e. what's inside my `.Xmodmap` file:

```
keysym Shift_R = Mode_switch

keycode 49 = asciicircum VoidSymbol degree degree notsign notsign
keycode 10 = 1 VoidSymbol exclam onesuperior exclamdown
keycode 11 = 2 VoidSymbol quotedbl quotedbl twosuperior oneeighth
keycode 12 = 3 VoidSymbol section numbersign threesuperior sterling
keycode 13 = 4 VoidSymbol dollar dollar onequarter currency
keycode 14 = 5 VoidSymbol percent percent onehalf threeeighths
keycode 15 = 6 VoidSymbol ampersand ampersand notsign fiveeighths

keycode 24 = q VoidSymbol Q Q at Greek_OMEGA
keycode 25 = w VoidSymbol W W lstroke Lstroke
keycode 26 = e VoidSymbol E E EuroSign EuroSign
keycode 27 = r VoidSymbol R R paragraph registered
keycode 28 = t VoidSymbol T T tslash Tslash

keycode 38 = a VoidSymbol A A ae AE
keycode 39 = s VoidSymbol S S U017F U1E9E
keycode 40 = d VoidSymbol D D eth ETH
keycode 41 = f VoidSymbol F F dstroke ordfeminine
keycode 42 = g VoidSymbol G G eng ENG

keycode 94 = less VoidSymbol greater greater bar dead_belowmacron bar dead_belowmacron
keycode 52 = y VoidSymbol Y Y guillemotright U203A
keycode 53 = x VoidSymbol X X guillemotleft U2039
keycode 54 = c VoidSymbol C C cent copyright
keycode 55 = v VoidSymbol V V doublelowquotemark singlelowquotemark
```

(Note that my mappings are for the German keyboard, you can see your default mappings using `xmodmap -pke`)